# HTML/PHP Confirmation on href

Tags: php, href, confirmation

I have this line of code that executes that runs a delete script for an item with a specific id which is retrieved from the url.

```
    echo " ( <a href=\"DeleteCategory.php?id="  . $row['id']    .   "\" >Delete</a> )";
```

How can I add an onclick confirmation that determines if it goes to the link or not.
I would rather not have to use any javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `onclick="return confirm ('Are you sure?')"`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ' ( <a href="DeleteCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want delete this catagory?\')">Delete</a> )';
```

The return value of an event handler determines whether or not the default browser behaviour should take place as well. In the case of clicking on links, this would be following the link.